# how to edit a text (.fastq) file in python

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I have a file like the small example below. every 4 line are related to one ID. the second line of each ID starts with N. I want to remove the N at the beginning of thoses lines and everything else would stay the same.
I want to do that in python. do you know how to do that?

example:

```
@SRR2163140.1 HISEQ:148:C670LANXX:3:1101:1302:1947 length=50
NGCGACCTCAGATCAGACGTGGCGACC
+SRR2163140.1 HISEQ:148:C670LANXX:3:1101:1302:1947 length=50
#<<ABGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
@SRR2163140.3 HISEQ:148:C670LANXX:3:1101:1381:1997 length=50
NGCCGACATCGAAGGATCAA
+SRR2163140.3 HISEQ:148:C670LANXX:3:1101:1381:1997 length=50
#<<ABFGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
@SRR2163140.4 HISEQ:148:C670LANXX:3:1101:1705:1940 length=50
NACAAACCCTTGTGTCGAGGGC
+SRR2163140.4 HISEQ:148:C670LANXX:3:1101:1705:1940 length=50
#=ABBGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
@SRR2163140.7 HISEQ:148:C670LANXX:3:1101:1704:1965 length=50
NGGGACATGACAGCCTGGACCATCG
+SRR2163140.7 HISEQ:148:C670LANXX:3:1101:1704:1965 length=50
#=ABBGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
```

output:

```
@SRR2163140.1 HISEQ:148:C670LANXX:3:1101:1302:1947 length=50
GCGACCTCAGATCAGACGTGGCGACC
+SRR2163140.1 HISEQ:148:C670LANXX:3:1101:1302:1947 length=50
#<<ABGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
@SRR2163140.3 HISEQ:148:C670LANXX:3:1101:1381:1997 length=50
GCCGACATCGAAGGATCAA
+SRR2163140.3 HISEQ:148:C670LANXX:3:1101:1381:1997 length=50
#<<ABFGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
@SRR2163140.4 HISEQ:148:C670LANXX:3:1101:1705:1940 length=50
ACAAACCCTTGTGTCGAGGGC
+SRR2163140.4 HISEQ:148:C670LANXX:3:1101:1705:1940 length=50
#=ABBGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
@SRR2163140.7 HISEQ:148:C670LANXX:3:1101:1704:1965 length=50
GGGACATGACAGCCTGGACCATCG
+SRR2163140.7 HISEQ:148:C670LANXX:3:1101:1704:1965 length=50
#=ABBGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
```

Comment: Be aware that to have valid fastq format, you would need to also remove the first character of the quality lines. What you want does not preserve the matching between bases and qualities.

Answer (score 4):

If I would do exactly what you ask (remove the starting N from each sequence), then that would leave the [FASTQ file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTQ_format) in an inconsistent state.

Every fourth line of a FASTQ file holds the quality values for the sequence two lines earlier. So If you remove the first character from the sequence you also need to remove the first character from the line with quality values.

You could do something very straightforward in pure Python like

```
with open("example.fastq") as f:
    for idx, line in enumerate(f.read().splitlines()):
        if idx % 2:
            print(line[1:])
        else:
            print(line)
```

but if you're going to be working with biological data regularly, you really should start using a bioinformatics module like [BioPython](http://biopython.org/wiki/Documentation). It will warn you if you try to do things that would leave the file in an inconsistent shape or that don't make sense.

The solution then looks like:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from Bio import Seq

new_records = []
for record in SeqIO.parse("example.fastq", "fastq"):
    sequence = str(record.seq)
    letter_annotations = record.letter_annotations

    # You first need to empty the existing letter annotations
    record.letter_annotations = {}

    new_sequence = sequence[1:]
    record.seq = Seq.Seq(new_sequence)


    new_letter_annotations = {'phred_quality': letter_annotations['phred_quality'][1:]}
    record.letter_annotations = new_letter_annotations

    new_records.append(record)


with open('without_starting_N.fastq', 'w') as output_handle:
    SeqIO.write(new_records, output_handle, "fastq")
```

which outputs

```
@SRR2163140.1 HISEQ:148:C670LANXX:3:1101:1302:1947 length=50
GCGACCTCAGATCAGACGTGGCGACC
+
<<ABGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
@SRR2163140.3 HISEQ:148:C670LANXX:3:1101:1381:1997 length=50
GCCGACATCGAAGGATCAA
+
<<ABFGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
@SRR2163140.4 HISEQ:148:C670LANXX:3:1101:1705:1940 length=50
ACAAACCCTTGTGTCGAGGGC
+
=ABBGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
@SRR2163140.7 HISEQ:148:C670LANXX:3:1101:1704:1965 length=50
GGGACATGACAGCCTGGACCATCG
+
=ABBGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
```

(the '+' character on every third line is *optionally* followed by the same sequence identifier and description from two lines earlier)